# Redirect to internal local ip and port without using /etc/hosts (nginx)

Tags: nginx, dns, vps, hosts, nas

I have a diy (poor man's) NAS and I can access the file-browser in my home-network by using the ip: `192.168.0.2:1111`

I could modify the `/etc/hosts` in each of my devices to redirect `my-fancy-filebrowser-url.com` to `192.168.0.2:1111`.

However, I want to find an alternative that does not involve modifying the `/etc/hosts` of each device in my network. I do not want to set up a local dns server either as it will probably slow down the resolution of internet domains, I am using `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1` to resolve domain names quicker.

One of those alternatives I found out, is by using nginx. I have purchased a domain name, let's call it `mydomain.com` and I have an **ipv6** VPS server. I have used **cloudflare** to redirect a url to my server **ipv6** address and I have installed nginx to my VPS and I have created this config file:

```
http {
    # redirect to my router page
    server {
        listen      [d6b6:8760:97ec:ea7a:562c:c954:bb8d:6e41]:80;
        return 302  http://192.168.0.1;
    }
    # redirect to filebrowser
    server {
        listen      [d6b6:8760:97ec:ea7a:562c:c954:bb8d:6e42]:80;
        return 302  http://192.168.0.2:1111;
    }
}
```

The redirect to my router admin page is working perfectly as expected (for anyone interested I pointed cloudflare `subdomain.mydomain.com` to the ipv6 address). But the filebrowser one is not. I suspect it is because I am trying to specify a port to redirect to. Is it possible to do something like this with nginx? Or is there any better alternative that does not involve modifying `/etc/hosts` or setting your own dns server?

**Edit:** my bad, I was actually inputting the ipv6 address incorrectly in cloudflare. It was missing 1 digit so it was never going to work. I corrected the ip and it works good. The accepted answer does it more cleverly with urls instead of hardcoding the ipv6 which is a good idea! Just note that if you are using a ipv6 server then you are going to listen in the `[::]:80` port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the IPv6 addresses in the `listen` directive and add [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directives instead:

```
http {
    # redirect to my router page
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name router.mydomain.com;
        return 302 http://192.168.0.1;
    }
    # redirect to filebrowser
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name filebrowser.mydomain.com;
        return 302 http://192.168.0.2:1111;
    }
}
```

> I do not want to set up a local dns server either as it will probably slow down the resolution of internet domains

This is probably a wrong assumption. Something like `dnsmasq` is able to resolve local names and forward all other DNS queries to upstream servers (like `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1`), caching the results. So when setup properly you wouldn't need a domain or a VPS in this case.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I tried this and the router is working as per my initial solution but the redirect to filebrowser is not working. So maybe it is just some deeper issue. I'll need to have a deeper look. Note that the filebrowser is running in my local network and not on the VPS server itself. Thank you for clearing out my false knowledge for the self-hosted dns server.